# How to correctly return and format an array of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the Gmail API to list unread messages in my PHP application. I have a lot to learn and am cobbling together different bits of code I've found on here. Everything works, but it doesn't quite display the way I'd like. My code returns:

```
["
FedEx Shipment Notification
Mar 27th 2017 04:26 PM
TrackingUpdates@fedex.com","

Wellness 2 - Sp17: Re: Mike's fault!
Mar 26th 2017 06:13 PM
JohnSmith@mail.com "]
```

How can I change the code to return only:

```
FedEx Shipment Notification
Mar 27th 2017 04:26 PM
TrackingUpdates@fedex.com

Wellness 2 - Sp17: Re: Mike's fault!
Mar 26th 2017 06:13 PM
JohnSmith@mail.com
```

...without the extra quotation marks, square brackets, and commas between e-mails? I know I'm missing some basic knowledge.

I've tried

```
substr($inboxMessage, 2)
```

...in the list_messages function as a starting point to get rid of the first quotation mark and square bracket, but I got the error "substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

I also tried

```
$inboxMessages = array();
```

instead of

```
$inboxMessages = []
```

...but that returned only one e-mail and it was still in quotes and brackets.

I've also tried adding a json_decode in the get_content function:

```
$this->content->items[] = json_decode($getmail->obtain_gmail_feed());
```

...which produced the error "Array to string conversion in /var/www/moodle/lib/outputcomponents.php on line 1082"

I don't know what else to try, and I'd greatly appreciate some help.

Here's the code in lib.php:

```
class get_gmail {

    function getHeader($headers, $name) {
        foreach($headers as $header) {
            if($header['name'] == $name) {
                return $header['value'];
            }
        }
    }

    function listMessages($service, $userId) {
        $list = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',
            ['maxResults' => 2, 'q' => 'in:inbox is:unread']);

        $messageList = $list->getMessages();
        $inboxMessage = [];

        foreach($messageList as $mlist){
            $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
            $single_message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$mlist->id, 
                $optParamsGet2);
            $message_id = $mlist->id;
            $headers = $single_message->getPayload()->getHeaders();

            foreach($headers as $single) {
                if ($single->getName() == 'Subject') {
                    $message_subject = '<p>'.$single->getValue().'<br />';
                }

                else if ($single->getName() == 'Date') {
                    $message_date = $single->getValue();
                    $message_date = date('M jS Y h:i A', 
                        strtotime($message_date)).'<br />';
                }

                else if ($single->getName() == 'From') {
                    $message_sender = $single->getValue();
                    $message_sender = str_replace('"', '', $message_sender);
                }
            }

            $inboxMessage[] =$message_subject.$message_date.$message_sender;
        }

        return $inboxMessage;
    }
}

public function obtain_gmail_feed() {
    global $CFG, $USER, $message_list;
    require_once($CFG->libdir . '/google/lib.php');

    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile($CFG-
        >wwwroot.'/blocks/sko_gmail/client_secret.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);   
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $gmail_service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
    $useremail = 'me';

    $message_list = $this->listMessages($gmail_service, $useremail);
    $message_list = json_encode($message_list);

    return $message_list;
}
```

Then in index.php:

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/blocks/sko_gmail/lib.php');

class block_sko_gmail extends block_list {
    public function get_content() {
        global $message_list;

        $this->content = new stdClass;
        $getmail = new get_gmail();
        $this->content->items  = array();
        $this->content->items[] = $getmail->obtain_gmail_feed();

        return $this->content;

    }
}
```

I would also welcome any suggestions on how to improve my code.

Comment: You can remove `$message_list = json_encode($message_list);` to not generate a json string. `$message_list = implode(PHP_EOL,$message_list);` makes more what you want.

Comment: I'd focus on the json_decode path. You're getting an error about an array to string conversion. What exactly do you get if you `var_dump($getmail->obtain_gmail_feed());`

Comment: show the output like mkaatman suggested but show the first data you get so we can see what format it arrives in  and how to extract the data instead of how to take the strings away

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, @JustOnUnderMillions! Thank you so much!